# Conversion from machine-local polar coordinates (yaw, pitch, roll) to global (azimuth, elevation)

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I'm writing a 3D LOGO module in Python.

I recently realized that my approach is flawed. What I implemented is: the turtle besides right/left commands which change its azimuth in the xy plane, received 'up' / 'down' which change the elevation - angle between xy plane and where the turtle is pointing. I got it to work, but realized this approach is very limiting - current position of the turtle doesn't affect the two angles, a turtle pointing straight up, told 'left 90' will be still pointing the same straight up, until lowered.

I'd like to implement something more akin to airplane controls. Pitch up/down, yaw left/right, roll clockwise/counterclockwise, and effects all depend on current position: a pilot oriented due north, performing pitch up 90 degrees, then yaw left 90 degrees will be facing due west, but is rolled 90 degrees - and should perform roll clockwise 90 degrees to return to level flight. Similarly, starting in flat flight after roll 180 degrees, input of pitch up (yoke back) results in plane's motion to pitch down.

How do I convert these operations (pitch up/down, yaw left/right, roll cw/ccw in the plane's frame of reference) to azimuth and elevation (and spin angle) in global frame of reference?

Comment: It’s not clear either what is the undesired behavior that you have achieved or what behavior you do desire. Would it help to translate the turtle to the origin, rotate, and then translate back?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Translation is completely outside of scope of this question. Assume the turtle is always at the origin (and I can deal with translation from there). The question is about translating rotation from the system of coordinates relative to the turtle ("up" is towards dorsal, "right" is towards starboard, "front" is bow) to ground ("front" is north, "up" is angled up from the horizon).

Comment: Sorry, I’m pretty rusty on turtle graphics, but… is this any harder than subtracting or adding the turtle’s current absolute orientation? If you want a rotate-rightward command that would, for instance, spin a turtle currently pointing toward 2 o’clock to point instead toward 5’oclock, then this would do it.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Not if it's upside down. In 2D it's trivial, turtle's "clockwise" is always global "clockwise". In 3D if you turn towards the turtle's right, and the turtle is upside down, you turn left. If the turtle spun (rolled) half a rotation right, 90 degrees right will point it due down.

Comment: Sure I could just go with what I have - azimuth+elevation, it's limiting though. If I angle the turtle up, and then move it in a 360 degree circle, it won't make a circle in the plane of its orientation - it will make a helix.